# remove identical documents or find unique documents from given corpus

Tags: text, nlp, document, similarity, tf-idf

I got a large corpus having documents like,

```
   docs = ['$5,203.67 PQWS Total amount..',
           '0175543284 - 3 Account No: Road..',
           '0175532443 - 4 Account No: Road..',
           '1341 Leister St 1804B Engineers..',
           '1341 Leister St 1804B Engineers..',
           '1804BA Engineers Rd, 17650 Hwy..',
           '508 Invoice Number: INTEGRIT..',
           'Account 034043 IMSS GO PARK To..',
           'Account 032312 IMSS PARK GO To..',
           'Account IMSS 556 Account ID In..']
```

```
   import numpy as np
   from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
   vect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)
   tfidf = vect.fit_transform(docs)
   tfidf * tfidf.T.A
```

By finding similarities between each other I got:

```
   array([[1.        , 0.46629119, 0.46629119, 0.10831311, 0.09808441,
           0.25865805, 0.14477914, 0.10474497, 0.14103214, 0.0716321 ],
          [0.46629119, 1.        , 1.        , 0.12442779, 0.12302486,
           0.30257841, 0.13178749, 0.11879581, 0.16644523, 0.09755522],
          [0.46629119, 1.        , 1.        , 0.12442779, 0.12302486,
           0.30257841, 0.13178749, 0.11879581, 0.16644523, 0.09755522],
          [0.10831311, 0.12442779, 0.12442779, 1.        , 0.64169025,
           0.46153048, 0.09864211, 0.06776454, 0.10726221, 0.03940867],
          [0.09808441, 0.12302486, 0.12302486, 0.64169025, 1.        ,
           0.47684479, 0.10604529, 0.07274002, 0.11338126, 0.05369127],
          [0.25865805, 0.30257841, 0.30257841, 0.46153048, 0.47684479,
           1.        , 0.13310362, 0.1096675 , 0.18187125, 0.0542392 ],
          [0.14477914, 0.13178749, 0.13178749, 0.09864211, 0.10604529,
           0.13310362, 1.        , 0.23109647, 0.21373637, 0.07414937],
          [0.10474497, 0.11879581, 0.11879581, 0.06776454, 0.07274002,
           0.1096675 , 0.23109647, 1.        , 0.54704854, 0.12338632],
          [0.14103214, 0.16644523, 0.16644523, 0.10726221, 0.11338126,
           0.18187125, 0.21373637, 0.54704854, 1.        , 0.13290278],
          [0.0716321 , 0.09755522, 0.09755522, 0.03940867, 0.05369127,
           0.0542392 , 0.07414937, 0.12338632, 0.13290278, 1.        ]])
```

Now I want to remove all identicals keep only one from each

so my desired output here is docs index no:

```
   [0,1,3,6,7,9]
```

These all docs are invoices and basically, I want to find all unique documents(formats) from the corpus. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you use tf-idf to do that ? Is your goal to automatically get the `[0,1,3,6,7,9]` list or to filter the corpus using this list ?

Comment: @ygorg I have used tf-idf to get the similarity of the document. and I want automatically to extract described indices.

Comment: @ygorg as an example my return corpus should be ``` [0,1,3,6,7,9]``` these index of docs. while docs[1] and docs[2] are identical so I want to have only one out of this. same as docs[3], docs[4] and docs[5] are identical so it should return only one out of 3 and so on. In short, I want to remove all identical texts and keep the only one that kind of.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the ids of duplicate documents from your similarity matrix I did this:

`set([min(x, y) for x, y in zip(*np.where(a > 0.5)) if x != y])`

```py
# Get matrix indices where the value is greater than 0.5
indexes = np.where(a > 0.5)

# Display the coordinate where the value is greater than 0.5 and is not on the diagonal
[(x, y) for x, y in zip(*indexes) if x != y]

# Select one of the document (consistently) and remove duplicates
to_remove = set([min(x, y) for x, y in zip(*np.where(a > 0.5)) if x != y])

# Remove duplicates documents in `docs`
docs = [d for i, d in enumerate(docs) if i not in to_remove]
```

But in my opinion using TfIdf to find duplicates is not the right tool, a CountVectorizer seem more suited. But both these tools do not account for the sequentiality of the text ('The mouse eat the cheese' and 'The cheese eat the mouse' would be exact matches !). An other approach would be to use text similarity algorithm such as the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or Hamming distance (which is faster).

```py
import jellyfish
to_remove = []
# For each document compute the distance
# alternatively for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(docs)), 2):
for i in range(len(docs)):
    for j in range(i, len(docs)):
        dist = jellyfish.levenshtein_distance(docs[i], docs[j])
        # If there is less than 3 insertion/deletion/substitution
        if dist < 3:
            # Remove document
            to_remove.append(j)

to_remove = set(to_remove)

# Remove duplicates documents in `docs`
docs = [d for i, d in enumerate(docs) if i not in to_remove]
```